# Group data in array of data table objects to different array of objects

Tags: c#, arrays, vb.net

i have the below data in the data table.

```
[
{'age': '25', 'name': 'mike'},
{'age': '25', 'name': 'john'},
{'age': '25', 'name': 'charles'},
{'age': '30', 'name': 'melanie'},
{'age': '30', 'name': 'cindy'}
]
```

I'd like to parse this array using Lodash or some not-so-messy way to get an array of objects where the Object has a key 'age' that maps to a string and a key 'names' that maps to an array of strings.

So the final resulting array would look like the following:

```
[
 {'age': '25', 'names': ['john', 'mike', 'charles']},
 {'age': '30', 'names': ['cindy', 'melanie']}
]
```

kindly suggest me a way forward in C# or VB.net to achieve this output.

Comment: That's a *malformed* JSON (assuming it's actually like that in the database and not  presented here malformed). If you replace the single quotes with double quotes, you can simply parse that JSON to .Net classes, use [GroupBy()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.groupby) to group the objects by `age` and [Select()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select) to return a new object built as you prefer.

Comment: do something like this `var temp = ls.GroupBy(x => x.age).ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.ToList());`

Answer (score 1):

Try following :

```
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("age", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("name", typeof(string));
            
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {25, "mike"});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {25, "john"});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {25, "charles"});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {30, "melanie"});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {30, "cindy"});

            var groups = dt.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(x => x.Field<int>("age"));

            foreach (var group in groups)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("age : '{0}', names : '{1}'", group.Key, string.Join(",", group.Select(x => x.Field<string>("name"))));
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: Indeed. and if you use strongly typed datatables, the code gets simpler: `foreach(var g in dt.GroupBy(r => r.Age))` `Console.WriteLine($"age : '{g.Key}', names : '{string.Join(",", g.Select(r => r.Name)}'")`